# jquery not clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a list

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="chosenflag" data-flag="de"><img class="flag" src="" alt="" /></a>
<ul class="choices">
        <li><a href="#" data-flag="en"><img class="flag" src="/img/flag/United Kingdom.png" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-flag="de"><img class="flag" src="/img/flag/Germany.png" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-flag="es"><img class="flag" src="/img/flag/Spain.png" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-flag="fr"><img class="flag" src="/img/flag/France.png" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-flag="it"><img class="flag" src="/img/flag/Italy.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
```

I'm trying to code in jQuery the ability to only allow an action on everything BUT list element thats data-flag matches the .chosenflag class

I tried the following but to no avail

**jQuery**

```
var compareflag = $('.chosenflag').attr('data-flag');
$('.choices li:not(.chosenflag[data-flag="'+compareflag+'") a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("clicked");
    });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/XCQdR/1/)
Could someone maybe help me out with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a variable during the declaration of an event handler as it will use the value for the assignment and then never change - it will always look for the same thing later.  Instead, do the comparison *inside* the event handler.  It's difficult to explain what I mean but here's the code and a working link...

```
$(".choices li a").click(function(e){
    var compareflag = $(".chosenflag").data("flag");
    if ($(this).data("flag") != compareflag) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("clicked");
    }
});​
```

**[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/XCQdR/12/)**

Comment: +1 The OP only wants to prevent default for the chosen flag, but that's a small change

Comment: why to use `attr('data-flag');` and `data("flag")` in same code ?

Comment: Just a copy and paste of the existing code - I added the `data()` tag myself.  Good point though, so I've changed it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var compareflag = $('.chosenflag').attr('data-flag');

$('.choices li a:not([data-flag="'+compareflag+'"])').click(function(e){   
    alert("clicked");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XCQdR/10/

Comment: How would :has change the functionality?  I have a working example, but I would be interested to hear your thoughts elaborated.  I think the OP wants to prevent clicks on links that have a data-flag that matches the chosenflag's data-flag.

Comment: That's why only one list item should get the click handler, not four

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:has` filter:

```
'.choices li:has(a[data-flag="'+compareflag+'"])'
```

[Example at JS Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XCQdR/5/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, you're missing `]`, but your selector is also wrong. You're using the `not` selector on the `li`, and are passing the `.chosenflag` class to it, it should be on the `a`, without the `.chosenflag` class, eg:

```
$('.choices li a:not([data-flag="' + compareflag + '"])')
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XCQdR/9/)